# CSOM send email with attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I need to send list item attachment via email whenever someone add an item to list. I am unable to send email with attachment. 
using SendGrid of azure as CSOM send email utility does not support attachment.

With send grid , I am unable to provide file url as it don’t accept (http://filepath ) (It only accept local path)

Is there any way to get list item attachment and convert it into system.IO.Stream

Is there any other approach or solution for this.

Implementing with Remote Event Receiver .

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the file attachment via CSOM or REST? Either should get you the FileStream.

Comment: I can retrieve attachment but not FileStream with system.IO.Stream. I can take stream with this Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File

Comment: Use the `OpenBinaryStream` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarystream.aspx) of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File`.  It will return a stream that you should be able to use.

Comment: yes I am able to. But when I am giving that stream as attachment parameter it says can not convert to System.IO.Stream

Comment: Hmm, does the returned object have a `Value` property?

Comment: Ohh Yes it has. Let me quickly test. I guess this will work.

Comment: Stream is coming Null but File.Name has correct value.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm at a loss then. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No problem !! Thank you very much , your help really made some movement at my end. :)

Comment: Please put your answer in answer section. It gives my answer. :)

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood.  `File.Name` had the Stream?

Comment: yes , I just forgot to call executequery . its solved and worked too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OpenBinaryStream` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarystream.aspx) of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` should return the file's stream:

```
var fileStream = attachment.OpenBinaryStream();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can also use the `OpenBinaryDirect` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537083.aspx):

```
var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, attachment.ServerRelativeUrl);
var fileStream = fileInfo.Stream;
```

`OpenBinaryDirect` does not require an `ExecuteQuery()` method call.

I copied part of @VadimGremyachev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056425/3581857) for the `OpenBinaryDirect` bit.